# asp.net image control - how to put an image in it

Tags: asp.net, image

I have a list of `System.Drawing.Image`. I want to update my asp.net `Image` control in the `Page_Load` event with the last image from that list.

I can only find properties like ImageURL. Can't I just do something like

```
ImageControl1.referenceToSomeImageObjectWhichWillBeDisplayed=myImageObjectFromTheList
```

is there any such property on the Image control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

To do what you want, you can write an [HTTP Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx) that returns the image and point the `ImageUrl` to it.

[Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/desaijm/httphandlersforimages11152005062705am/httphandlersforimages.aspx) is one example of such a handler.

Answer (score 2):

Oded is correct i would use a handler to return the Image. Example below:

**Handler Class**:

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{

public void ProcessRequest( HttpContext context )
{
    try
    {
        String Filename = context.Request.QueryString[ "FileName" ];

        if ( !String.IsNullOrEmpty( Filename ) )
        {
            // Read the file and convert it to Byte Array 
            string filename = context.Request.QueryString[ "FileName" ];
            string contenttype = "image/" + Path.GetExtension( Filename.Replace( ".", "" ) );
            FileStream fs = new FileStream( filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read );
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader( fs );
            Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes( ( Int32 ) fs.Length );
            br.Close();
            fs.Close();

            //Write the file to response Stream 
            context.Response.Buffer = true;
            context.Response.Charset = "";
            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability( HttpCacheability.NoCache );
            context.Response.ContentType = contenttype;
            context.Response.AddHeader( "content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename );
            context.Response.BinaryWrite( bytes );
            context.Response.Flush();
            context.Response.End();
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception )
    {
        throw;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets whether the handler is reusable
/// </summary>
public bool IsReusable
{
    get { return true; }
}
}
```

I then added a common Page method to use the handler:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Gets the image handler query
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ImagePath">The path to the image</param>
    /// <returns>Image Handler Query</returns>
    protected string GetImageHandlerQuery(string ImagePath)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ImagePath != string.Empty)
            {
                string Query = String.Format("..\\Handlers\\ImageHandler.ashx?Filename={0}", ImagePath);

                return Query;
            }
            else
            {
                return "../App_Themes/Dark/Images/NullImage.gif";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

And finally to use in the ASPX:

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="btnThumbnail" runat="server" CommandName="SELECT" src='<%# GetImageHandlerQuery((string)Eval("ImageThumbnail200Path")) %>'
                                                                            ToolTip='<%#(string) Eval("ToolTip") %>' Style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 200px" />
```

or if you wanted to use in Code Behind:

```
 imgPicture.ImageUrl = this.GetImageHandlerQuery( this.CurrentPiecePicture.ImageOriginalPath );
```

Obviously you dont need the page method and you can call the handler directly but it might be useful to put in your base page class.